# How to deal with uid being interpreted different, different places?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user) {
                let uid = user.uid;
                database.ref('EmailList').child(uid).set({                    
                    uid: document.getElementById("myTextArea").value,
                }); 
            }
        });
```

Can some one explain to me, why uid in:

```
database.ref('EmailList').child(uid).set({
```

works as I intended with replacing it with the firebase uid, but doesn't afterwards when trying to place it as a name?

And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In this statement -

```
database.ref('EmailList').child(uid).set({
  uid: document.getElementById("myTextArea").value,
});
```

... first `uid` is a reference to the corresponding variable (and its value) set in your code, but the second one is a literal string 'uid' used as an object key.

It seems that you want either this...

```
database.ref('EmailList').child(uid)
  .set(document.getElementById("myTextArea").value);
```

... or (far less likely, but useful as an example) this:

```
database.ref('EmailList').set({
  [uid]: document.getElementById("myTextArea").value
});
```

In the last case, the value of `uid` variable will be used as a key. Note that this op will overwrite all the current values of `EmailList` field.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are literally setting a child node named "uid" in the database:

```
let uid = user.uid;
database.ref('EmailList').child(uid).set({                    
    uid: document.getElementById("myTextArea").value,
});
```

If you want to set a property name from the variable `uid`, you will want to use JavaScript syntax to substitute that variable as the name of the property:

```
database.ref('EmailList').child(uid).set({                    
    [uid]: document.getElementById("myTextArea").value,
});
```

Note the angle brackets around "uid".